# Reuse parts of snakemake results

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I have been using a modified version of the [snakemake implementation of the GATK pipeline](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/dna-seq-gatk-variant-calling) for genotyping. The pipeline first maps reads to the reference and calls variants per sample. Subsequently, variants are analyses jointly in a genotyping step. Now I want to run a new analysis workflow based in part on the same samples.

Is there a way to re-use the sample-specific rule results from previous analyses workflows such that they do not need to be recomputed? And what is the best practice for doing this; e.g. copying / symlinking data or using between workflow caching (can caching be done retro-actively) ?

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you already mention your options in the question. I would go for symlinking. I think caching is mainly used for assemblies/genomes and their indices.